# how to skip login screen when sending an email using GMAIL API?

Tags: email, gmail-api

I am working on an web application from which email is send to clients every day for status and i want to send email using **GMAIL API** but when i try to login using GMAIL API it opens a login page in which credentials has to be entered and then it passes the control to my servlet. My question is there a way to skip or automate this login process?

Comment: Try using offline access to our Oauth for your application? check this link https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer. This prevents user to be prompted with consent screen for authorizing your app. Let me know if your case is different.